# PHP calculator not returning value

Tags: php

Hi im very new to this stuff. My PHP calculator returns nothing when I hit calculate, when I upload this file to my 000webhost site. I don't have the website up right now but here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" action="#">

Enter the First Number <input type="text" name="number1"> <br><br>

Enter the Second Number <input type="text" name="number2"><br><br>

Choose the operation 

Addition <input type="radio" name="op" value="add" checked>

Subtraction <input type="radio" name="op" value="sub">

Multiplication <input type="radio" name="op" value="mul">

Division<input type="radio" name="op" value="div"><br><br>

 <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if ( $op == "add" ) {
  echo "$number1 + $number2 = ";
  echo $number1 + $number2;
}

if ( $op == "sub" ) {
  echo "$number1 - $number2 = ";
  echo $number1 - $number2;
}

if ( $op == "mul" ) {
  echo "$number1 * $number2 = ";
  echo $number1 * $number2;
}

if ( $op == "div" ) {
  echo "$number1 / $number2 = ";
  echo $number1 / $number2;
}

?>
<html>
```

When I hit calculate nothing happens and the link gets a question mark in it. Please help.

Comment: You never actually use any values from the form. I would suggest a tutorial on the basics. Also, check your PHP's error log, it should be filled with warning and notices that can set you on the right path.

Comment: `$op` is not defined. Any PHP/HTML forms tutorial would show you how to correctly obtain the submitted data from a form. What have you studied so far?

Comment: In addition to the problems mentioned by others, you are trying to output after the closing html tag. Who knows what browsers do with that. They may very well ignore it.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `$_GET` for accessing input value from get form request

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get" >

    Enter the First Number <input type="text" name="number1"> <br><br>

    Enter the Second Number <input type="text" name="number2"><br><br>

    Choose the operation
<br>
     <input type="radio" name="op" value="add" checked>Addition<br>

     <input type="radio" name="op" value="sub">Subtraction<br>

     <input type="radio" name="op" value="mul">Multiplication<br>

    <input type="radio" name="op" value="div">Division<br><br>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

if (isset( $_GET['number1']) && isset( $_GET['number2']) && isset( $_GET['op'])) {
    $number1 = $_GET['number1'];
    $number2 = $_GET['number2'];

    $op = $_GET['op'];
    if ($op == "add") {
        echo "$number1 + $number2 = ";
        echo $number1 + $number2;
    }

    if ($op == "sub") {
        echo "$number1 - $number2 = ";
        echo $number1 - $number2;
    }

    if ($op == "mul") {
        echo "$number1 * $number2 = ";
        echo $number1 * $number2;
    }

    if ($op == "div") {
        echo "$number1 / $number2 = ";
        echo $number1 / $number2;
    }
}


?>
<html>
```

Comment: @ADyson thanks man, all of u guys. Sorry if I was annoying, I dont know anything im new and still learning.

Comment: @DeCode it's fine we all have to learn. We will try to help where we can.

Comment: @ADyson how can i display an error message for a non numerical input or an input of nothing (e.g. "you must input a value"). Would this use a switch function?

Comment: @DeCode Like I said, if you have a new problem, post a new question (not just a comment)